# Push topic connection in salesforce is time out within few seconds (sandbox - Winter 20) and gives the error 403::Unknown Client

Tags: sandbox, workbench, pushtopic, streaming

I'm trying to connect push topic server via workbench. But connection is dropping within few seconds. The permission required for the login user to connect streaming API was given in the sandbox. What could be the possible reason for continuous connection drop?

[image]